# What happens to questions closed as duplicate in the long term?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, voting

#### Subtitle: When is it OK to up vote duplicate questions?

I have found many questions marked as [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/duplicate) pretty useful, to find answers for research on SO. Even if the final question/answer didn't match the exact requirements I'm looking for, going my way through the linked duplicate questions, gives a good way to figure out the points to resolve the actual problem.

Now, if I mark a question as duplicate, what will happen with it on the long term? Is this question: [***"How to dummy-proof invalid input in c++; error output keeps looping? [duplicate]"***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26025765/how-to-dummy-proof-invalid-input-in-c-error-output-keeps-looping) about to be deleted, or will it stay around as long up voted and popular enough?

In other words: Will up voting preserve a duplicate from being deleted and help to improve the (wiki part) of the SE network?

I think the OP has shown all necessary efforts, to ask a valid question according the [SO policies](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and thus decided to upvote it, as being helpful for future researchers.

Comment: @Prix Why does it need a direct answer to be protected from deletion? The linked dupe well provides answers. I know, because I've been writing them, and don't want to write them again. Though I think the question I've marked, is valid, and the OP has shown to make all necessary efforts asking it. I think the question is useful for future researchers, and thus upvoted accordingly.

Comment: [`Some duplicate questions may eventually be deleted, but often they are left as a signpost pointing people towards the canonical answer to that question.`](http://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates) So I guess its pretty much a entry point for search leading to an answer.

Comment: @Prix I well know this link, I've in fact provided it for that questions OP in a comment.

Comment: I am failing to see your point here, that FAQ does answer your question, it will be around as a signpost to users searching for the same thing. If it does get down voted to certain threshold it gets deleted I think -3 -5?

Answer (score 4):

There are two roomba scripts that will consider duplicates.  These are detailed in [Enable automatic deletion of old, unanswered zero-score questions after a year?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year).  The 9 day script (the one that hits most closed questions) doesn't look at duplicates, nor does the turbo charged deletion script described in [Turbocharging the Roomba: solutions for premature deletion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/177675/213963).

A duplicate that has a score of 0 or greater, or an answer will remain for at least 30 days.

A duplicate with more than 2 comments, an answer, a non negative score<sup>1</sup>, or a reasonable number of views<sup>2</sup> will stick around forever.

Those notes:

1. If the owner is deleted (from some other inactivity script for example, or never joined SO after the question was migrated here), the a question with score of 1 will be deleted.
2. The reasonable number of views is 1.5 views/day.  If it has 1000 views, it will stick around for 5 years given the other requirements for deletion are also meet.

The duplicate linked: [How to dummy-proof invalid input in c++; error output keeps looping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26025765/how-to-dummy-proof-invalid-input-in-c-error-output-keeps-looping) has two or more comments (this keeps the 365 day script away from it), and a score of 0 or more (this keeps the 30 day script away from it).  It will never be deleted under the current deletion scripts (unless someone down votes it).

Given the comment requirement for the 365 day script, it does not mater how popular (or unpopular) the duplicate is - it the 365 day script is hands off any post that has two or more comments, and the 30 day script won't touch questions that have a score of 0 or more.

If the question had an answer before it was marked duplicate, neither script would ever look at it.

Note that this says absolutely nothing about 10k+ rep users with delete votes after two days (who could also just down vote it instead...).  Given that this is indeed a signpost to another low visibility question, I doubt they would poke at it.... they're much more likely to be interested in deleting some of the poorly asked [~650](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/218384?lq=1) dups of the canonical NPE question that are still sticking around (many with FGITW answers).

Comment: THX for the insight! _"If the question had an answer before it was marked duplicate, neither script would ever look at it."_ That makes me question my reaction, if it would have been better to give a short answer (even only containing a link to the dupe), and close as duplicate afterwards (to achieve my intends, which are valid IMHO).

Comment: Do note that a link to the dup could get flagged as NAA (I have cast such flags in the past and had the flag acted upon).  The best thing to do is to make the question a well written one... but it is a reasonably well written one.  I don't see people wanting to down vote it.  The problem with signpost dups is when there are so many *poorly* written ones pointing there... like the NPE in Java example where there are hundreds of negatively scored dups to it with a simple answer that isn't that good either.

Comment: The other thing to consider that if it is indeed the ***exact*** same question (and thats a mod threshold for the wording of exact rather than a dup threshold), then you may consider asking a mod to merge the question.  The merge will then lock the original one... however, that destroys the content of the merged question (note that 'exact' bit above), which likely wouldn't be a good choice here.

Comment: As to the 'subtle' question mentioned - yes, it perfectly legitimate to up vote a duplicate.  The mouseover reads 'it shows research, it is useful and clear' - this is independent of its nature as a dup.

Comment: I agree merging, wouldn't give a good result here. As mentioned, posting a minimal answer showing the essentials and linking for the dupe + closing as duplicate answer looks like the most appropriate reaction here (being less likely to be closed as NAA).