# Reduce reputation for duplicate questions

Tags: feature-request

I think that simply putting a question on hold for being a duplicate is not enough to educate a duplicator. I've seen cases where a user would just keep asking the same question.

Also, getting negative reputation from duplicate questions may end up triggering the question ban algorithm on the duplicator, which would also be a good thing.

Comment: We can't assume that existing duplicates mean that the asker didn't search for an answer first. -1.

Comment: Duplicates create waysigns to a canonical answer, and *can* be well-asked and otherwise of desirable quality. No need to punish these.

Comment: If somebody is spamming *exact* duplicates of their own questions, just downvote, VtC if you can, and move on.

Comment: You are looking at the wrong audience.  Stack Overflow is not only for the person asking the question (educating a duplicator) but also making useful information findable for the ***next*** person with the question.  Duplicates help that larger audience that never needed to ask the question.

Comment: If the duplicate is obvious they will be downvoted anyways. They are already likely losing rep if they did no research.

Comment: Reputation is not exactly on such a user's mind.  Nor are question bans btw, there is no ban anymore.  Just a delay.  Less complaining that way, happier users.

Answer (score 5):

> *"I think that simply putting a question on hold for being a duplicate is not enough to educate a duplicator."*

### I seriously disagree!

There'´s **really nothing wrong with duplicates** asked in general, and they don't  even indicate for low research efforts of the OP in most cases.

Sometimes duplicate questions are really showing low efforts, and they are all plain accessible Q&A showing up at the **Related** section, or when a question is typed in.

But in fact, for most of the cases, duplicates may be hard to find, and sometimes I even upvote [duplicate questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26025765/how-to-dummy-proof-invalid-input-in-c-error-output-keeps-looping), if they deserve it.

Marking duplicates, is about the POV of the overall big network, and to help future researchers to find the right stuff on SO.

I have a list of favorite Q&A on SO, and whenever I see a particular pattern in a question, that well matches one of these, I'm going to propose, or mark it as a dupe. **I won't downvote such questions in 1st place**, unless it obviously has an overly easy to find answer with a dupe.

Also related: [*"What happens to questions closed as duplicate in the long term?"*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272111/what-happens-to-questions-closed-as-duplicate-in-the-long-term)

Comment: FWIW before knowing the actual search terms, it was hard for me to find the right posts on a specific code problem (google just works with keywords, can't give them a lot of semantics)

Comment: @MarcoA. Yes, it might be hard to find the dupes right away with keywords of a question. You'll need to know the right keywords, and may be additional context narrowing tags. Experience and _seen that, been there_ is oné of the least resorts that might help finding the right answer (IMHO That's why we've been provided with [**mjölnir**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254589/when-did-i-get-close-vote-superpowers/254590#254590) at least).